# How can I call include(left join) when the model to be included is not directly associated to the base model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join

There are three models that i want to join, booking, subbooking and client. A booking has_many sub_bookings also a booking belongs to(also may not) a client. I want to list all the sub_bookings ordered by the client.name. I need a join on booking and subhooking and an include relationship between booking and client. I tried the following and it didnt work.

```
SubBooking.joins(:booking).includes(:booking=>:client).order('client.name')
```

The models are as follows

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :sub_bookings
  ...
end

class SubBooking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
  ...
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  ...
end
```

To be more precise the SQL I want to be generated is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM sub_bookings 
INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = sub_bookings.booking_id
LEFT JOIN Clients ON bookings.client_id = clients.id
ORDER BY client.name
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Did it give you an error message?

Comment: yes there was a long error message. I dont have access to it I'll post it as soon as i get back to my machine.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I think I found something close to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code. I have created the application you described in your question and tried a few simple queries. Next I tried your sample query seen on line one in the output below.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > SubBooking.joins(:booking).include(:booking=>:client).order('client.name').to_sql
NoMethodError:   SubBooking Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sub_bookings".* FROM "sub_bookings" INNER JOIN "bookings" ON "bookings"."id" = "sub_bookings"."booking_id"
undefined method `include' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
        from /home/devin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/devin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from /home/devin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/devin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > SubBooking.joins(:booking).includes(:booking=>:client).order('client.name').to_sql
 => "SELECT \"sub_bookings\".* FROM \"sub_bookings\" INNER JOIN \"bookings\" ON \"bookings\".\"id\" = \"sub_bookings\".\"booking_id\" ORDER BY client.name"
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 >
```

As you see it throws a nice error which is what you may have seen, simply correcting the call from this:

```
SubBooking.joins(:booking).include(:booking=>:client).order('client.name')
```

To this:

```
SubBooking.joins(:booking).includes(:booking=>:client).order('client.name')
```

resolves the error.

If you would like to see the code I used its on [GitHub over here](https://github.com/devinmrn/user1064946_sandbox). Let me know if you have any more questions.

Regards,
Devin M

Comment: sorry for the typo Devin, and thanks that you put it on a sandbox

Comment: No problem, hopefully that's the problem you were facing. Let me know if that works for you when you get back to your machine.

Comment: sorry for the typo Devin as I wrote this from what i remember and not copy pasting the exact code, and thanks that you put it on a sandbox, 
but I am sure that I never saw this kind of error (undefined method `include') i used 'includes' for sure. Have you tested it with 'includes'. BTW i am using Ruby 1.8.7 does it make any difference ?

Comment: Yep see the second line, when using includes it works fine. I don't know if the lack of a LEFT JOIN is due to having no data on which to perform the join or an issue with the code.

Comment: well its strange and I am amazed but its working now, the very same line didnt work on console last night.
`SubBooking Load (34.3ms)  SELECT `sub_bookings`.`id` AS t0_r0,
...

FROM `sub_bookings` INNER JOIN `bookings` ON `bookings`.`id` = `sub_bookings`.`booking_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`id` = `bookings`.`client_id` WHERE (`sub_bookings`.`created_at` >= '2011-09-25' AND `sub_bookings`.`created_at` < '2011-11-25') ORDER BY sub_bookings.property_name asc, clients.name `